# Is is possible to strip a call stack from an exception string?

Tags: c#, exception

Exceptions are used throughout the component I'm working in for API error handling:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // ex.ToString() below may be something like "database is locked"
    string error = string.Format(
        "Error when trying to create a playlist: {0}", ex.ToString());
    throw new Exception(error);
}
```

Basically a lower-level component will throw an `Exception` with detailed specifics of the error, and this will be caught at a higher-level with a more generic, user-friendly error message.

When my client application processes this application, it calls `ex.ToString()` to get the complete error string, but this also includes the call stack.

```
Error: exceptions.RuntimeError: Error when trying to create a playlist: 
System.Exception: database is locked
at <very large call stack here>
```

Is there an easy way to prevent the last section (i.e. `at <very large call stack here>`) from appearing in the error message, without having the parse the string?  This is being returned to the user and I want the error to be user-focused not application-focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`Exception.Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message.aspx) instead of `Exception.ToString`:

```
string message = string.Format(
    "Error when trying to create a playlist: {0}", ex.Message);
throw new YourException(message, ex);
```

Comment: Too easy - thanks.  Any way to prevent `exceptions.RuntimeError` being displayed at the beginning.  i.e. I only want the raw error string displayed.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat: I suspect its the same answer... use Exception.Message when displaying the exception. Can you post the code you use to display the exception?

Comment: My apologies - it's a Python wrapper which is prepending this extra text to the start of the error string.  Thanks for your help.